# How to find data from array by multiple field values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to find data from multiple field values. suppose this is my data

```
const countryData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Afghanistan',
        isoAlpha2: 'AF',
        isoAlpha3: 'AFG',
        isoNumeric: 4,
        currency: {
            code: 'AFN',
            name: 'Afghani',
            symbol: '؋'
        },
        callingCodes: ['+93'],
        languages: ['pus'],
        emoji: ''
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Albania',
        isoAlpha2: 'AL',
        isoAlpha3: 'ALB',
        isoNumeric: 8,
        currency: {
            code: 'ALL',
            name: 'Lek',
            symbol: 'L'
        },
        callingCodes: ['+355'],
        languages: ['sqi'],
        emoji: ''
    }
]
```

Here, I need to find data by `name` or `isoAlpha2` or `isoAlpha3`.

```
const search = (query) => {
   //I need to define function
}
```

here function can be called-

```
search({name: "Afghanistan"}),
search({isoAlpha2: "Afghanistan"}),
search({name: "Afghanistan", isoAlpha2: "AF"}),
search({name: "Afghanistan", isoAlpha3: "AFG"})
```

here can be any combination of `name`, `isoAlpha2` or `isoAlpha3`

I need to find which one combination sent from function calling. I hope I can clear my question?

Answer (score 0):

look t snippet, is it what you are looking for?

```js
const countryData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    isoAlpha2: 'AF',
    isoAlpha3: 'AFG',
    isoNumeric: 4,
    currency: {
      code: 'AFN',
      name: 'Afghani',
      symbol: '؋'
    },
    callingCodes: ['+93'],
    languages: ['pus'],
    emoji: ''
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Albania',
    isoAlpha2: 'AL',
    isoAlpha3: 'ALB',
    isoNumeric: 8,
    currency: {
      code: 'ALL',
      name: 'Lek',
      symbol: 'L'
    },
    callingCodes: ['+355'],
    languages: ['sqi'],
    emoji: ''
  }
];


const search = (obj) => {
  let arr = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const countries = Object.values(obj);
  for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < countryData.length; i++) {
      if (countryData[i][keys[j]] === countries[j]) {
        arr.push(countryData[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

// search by name
let c = search({
  name: "Afghanistan"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

// search by isoAlpha2
c = search({
  isoAlpha2: "AF"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

// search by isoAlpha3
c = search({
  isoAlpha3: "AFG"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

// search by 2 keys -> same country
c = search({
  name: "Afghanistan",
  isoAlpha2: "AF"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

// search by 2 keys -> same country
c = search({
  name: "Afghanistan",
  isoAlpha3: "AFG"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

// search by 2 keys -> different country
c = search({
  name: "Afghanistan",
  isoAlpha3: "ALB"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
```